# Join syntax for Linq to SQL based on numeric range not foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, linq

What is the Linq to SQL syntax for joining entities using a numeric range?

Simple example (I'll show the tabular data for each entity rather than the C# code - and will omit the Id column):

"Item" entity

```
Name  | Price
--------------
Sofa  | 250.00
Table | 150.00
Chair | 50.00
```

"PriceBand" entity

```
Name  | PriceFrom | PriceTo
---------------------------
A     | 0         | 100
B     | 100       | 200
C     | 200       | 300
```

In SQL I would do:

```
select i.Name, b.Band 
from Item i
inner join PriceBand b on i.Price > b.PriceFrom 
                       and i.Price < b.PriceTo
```

with this result:

```
Chair   A
Table   B
Sofa    C
```

Note that I do not have any key relationship between these two entities / tables to help me out - just the price / price range relationship.

But how to do that in Linq to SQL?  I don't mind lambda syntax or query syntax - can't figure it out myself either way...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectMany` operator for such join:

```cs
var query =
    from i in context.Item
    from b in context.PriceBand
        .Where(b => i.Price > b.PriceFrom 
            && i.Price < b.PriceTo)
    select new 
    {
        i.Name, 
        b.Band 
    };
```

Documentation: [Complex Query Operators - Collection selector references outer in a where clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-where-clause)

Comment: yes, well done Svyatoslav. I'd like to point out that although correct and awesome - still we're left with a SelectMany happening without it being mentioned in the query, and also we have a mix of lamba and query syntax. I guess that's the nature of the beast.

Comment: Two `from` is `SelectMany`. We can use query syntax for whole query, but I prefer this "mix" - more readable.